# Expanding "$@" at until statement inside a function

Tags: bash

It's obvious that

```
# type 1
until "echo hi"; do :; done
```

does not work, since the syntax of `until` should be like this

```
# type 2
echo hi; until [ $? -eq 0 ]; do echo hi; done
```

in order to make sure that `hi` is printed succesfully.

However, I found that

```
# type 3 (similar to type 1)
function makesure { until "$@"; do :; done }
makesure echo hi
```

also works as expected, but I have no idea why it does work.

Is `type 3` semantically equal to `type 2`? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put quotes around `"echo hi"`, it looking for a command with that as the whole name, not executing the `echo` command with the parameter `hi`. It should be:

```
until echo hi; do :; done
```

it works in your function because `"$@"` quotes each parameter separately, so it's equivalent to:

```
until "echo" "hi"; do :; done;
```

The function would be equivalent to type 1 if you'd use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`, since that quotes all the parameters together, rather than separately.